# How to replace a SOQL query with a string?

Tags: soql, query, string

Any idea how to convert a query into a string?

Comment: P.S. no need to copy the list, just query and return, e.g. `return (List<AggregateResult>)Database.query(query);`

Comment: You have an extra single quote on the `From Fee` line

Comment: Why did you remove most of your question?  The idea of this site is that others can find your question and learn from it. Removing most of your question makes that impossible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `for (List<AggregateResult> agg: query)` you should have `for (List<AggregateResult> agg: Database.query(query))`.

You can find additional detail regarding Dynamic SOQL [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm).

Best regards!